# Retrive only taxonomy from a url generated by get_term_link in WP

Tags: wordpress

I have this code

```
$ret .= '<a class="tourmaster-tour-category-head-link" href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($category->term_id, $taxonomy)) . '" >';
```

that print this URL

http://example.com/tour-destination/america/ or.. http://example.com/tour-destination/europa/ etc..

How to keep only taxonomy slug (example: "america" ) from this url?

My goal is to replace this function and create a search url, something like this one:

```
$ret .= '<a class="tourmaster-tour-category-head-link" href="http://example.com/search-tours/?tour-search=&tax-tour-destination= ' . esc_url(get_term_link($category->term_id, $taxonomy)) . '" >';
```

to have a URL like:

```
http://example.com/search-tours/?tour-search=&tax-tour-destination=america
```

How to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already should have it in your $category object. Assuming that is actually a $term; If you not you can easily get it.

```
$slug = $category->slug;

or

$term = get_term( $category->term_id, $taxonomy );
$slug = $term->slug;

$ret .= '<a class="tourmaster-tour-category-head-link" href="example.com/search-tours/' . $slug . '" >';
```

Comment: So, how to change this tring to make it work?

$ret .= '<a class="tourmaster-tour-category-head-link" href="http://example.com/search-tours/?tour-search=&tax-tour-destination= ' . esc_url(get_term_link($category->term_id, $taxonomy)) . '" >';

Comment: Edited my answer to include the link